# Need some suggestions

Tags: ruby

I want to learn ruby so that I can use it to build my own product.

Few challenges I am facing:

1. Searching on internet doesn't give proper details about ruby study materials
2. Need proper ruby course material
3. Need some good projects written in ruby
4. Best coding practices in ruby

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow cannot help you with those questions, I suggest you look for Ruby-focused groups and forums instead. What Stack Overflow *can* help you with is specific coding or comprehension problems you face when learning. So if and when you face one of those, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I heard a lots of good things about  http://railsforzombies.org,  tho i never used it my self. Seems like interesting concept, worth to try.